# How do I find the second MODE in google spreadhseet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list of numbers and I am using =MODE to find the number which appears most often, my question is how do I find the second most often occurring number in the same list?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Sheets, you can use the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?rd=1) function to retrieve this sort of information (and much more)  quite easily. Assuming your data is numerical values only in column A with no header:

`=QUERY({A:A,A:A},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc",0)`

will return a list of the items in column A, and their associated frequencies, sorted from highest to lowest. Note: if column A contains text strings, you need to use `where Col1 != ''` rather than `where Col1 is not null`.

Now you can use INDEX to retrieve the exact value you require; so to retrieve the second most frequent value, you need the third value in the first column (as QUERY will populate a header row in the output):

`=INDEX(QUERY({A:A,A:A},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc",0),3,1)`